# Why do Mvc Maproutes seem to break the DRY principle

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I added the following route into my MVC app.

```
routes.MapRoute("leads", "leads/{leadId}", new { controller = "Leads", action = "ViewLead" });
```

However, it seems that any action method off the leads controller now causes it to try to go to the ViewLead action, and no id will be passed as its an action.
I was a little disappointed to then have to add the following to my routes just so I don't get an exception on my other actions:

```
    routes.MapRoute("leadIndex", "leads", new { controller = "Leads", action = "Index" });
    routes.MapRoute("leadAdd", "leads/addlead", new { controller = "Leads", action = "AddLead" });            
    routes.MapRoute("leadsSearch", "leads/searchleads", new { controller = "Leads", action = "SearchLeads" });            
    routes.MapRoute("leadsGetAll", "leads/getallleads", new { controller = "Leads", action = "GetAllLeads" });
    routes.MapRoute("leadsUpdate", "leads/updatelead", new { controller = "Leads", action = "UpdateLead" });
    routes.MapRoute("leadsRecipients", "leads/getrecipients", new { controller = "Leads", action = "GetRecipients" });
```

Am I doing anything wrong here? It seems to go against DRY principle in that I didn't have to specify these routes before, but now I do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason all your routes are being matched to the leads/{leadId} route is because it matches the pattern of {string}/{string}. What you need to do is add a constraint that says the leadid is an int.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "leads", 
    "leads/{leadId}", 
    new { controller = "Leads", action = "ViewLead" },
    new { leadId = @"\d+" });
```

This will only match the route when the parameter in the second position has at least 1 or more integers.

However, if you wanted to have multiple custom routes with the same base, check out this post by Phil Haack: http://haacked.com/archive/2010/12/02/grouping-routes-part-1.aspx

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great thanks! I didn't know you could add constraints to the routes.